# How to query nested json with internal arrays in Spark on basis of equality check

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I have a nested json structure loaded into a dataframe in spark. It contains several layers of arrays and I'm trying to figure out how to query this structure by values in the internal arrays.

**Example:** consider the following structure (directors.json file)

```
[
  {
    "director": "Steven Spielberg",
    "films": [
      {
        "name": "E.T",
        "actors": ["Henry Thomas", "Drew Barrymore"]
      },
      {
        "name": "The Goonies",
        "actors": ["Sean Astin", "Josh Brolin"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
    "films": [
      {
        "name": "Pulp Fiction",
        "actors": ["John Travolta", "Samuel L. Jackson"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Kill Bill: Vol. 1",
        "actors": ["Uma Thurman", "Daryl Hannah"]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Lets say I want to run a query that will return all the films that a specific actor has participated in. something like this:

```
val directors = spark.read.json("directors.json")
directors.select($"films.name").where($"films.actors" === "Henry Thomas")
```

When I run this in the spark shell I get an exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`films`.`actors` = 'Henry Thomas')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`films`.`actors` = 'Henry Thomas')' (array<array<string>> and string).;;
'Project [name#128]
+- 'Filter (films#92.actors = Henry Thomas)
   +- AnalysisBarrier
         +- Project [films#92.name AS name#128, films#92]
            +- Relation[director#91,films#92] json
```

How do I properly make such a query?

Are there different alternatives? If So, what are the pros and cons?

Thanks

**Edit**

@thebluephantom this still doesn't work. getting similar exception. 
I think it's because I have an array within another array. This is the exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(`films`.`actors`, 'Henry Thomas')' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be an array followed by a value of same type as the array members;;
'Filter array_contains(films#7.actors, Henry Thomas)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [director#6, films#7]
         +- Relation[director#6,films#7] json
```

Comment: I guess I expected it to be simpler but this works just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this whereby the film data must be exploded which means the repeating group of actors is simple normalized - otherwise I cannot get it to work either - maybe someone else can:

More complete using SPARK 2.3.1 as follows with your data:

```
val df = spark.read
   .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
   .json("/FileStore/tables/films.txt")

val flattened = df.select($"director", explode($"films").as("films_flat"))
flattened.select ("*").where (array_contains (flattened("films_flat.actors"), "Henry Thomas")).show(false)
```

returns:

```
 +----------------+-------------------------------------+
 |director        |films_flat                           |
 +----------------+-------------------------------------+
 |Steven Spielberg|[[Henry Thomas, Drew Barrymore], E.T]|
 +----------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: still fails. added new exception in the question body

Comment: Need to use explode on actors - which makes sense.

Comment: Nesting oi nesting, indeed some improvements can be made, that said, it's still pretty hot stuff. Success

Answer (score 0):

**problem statement :** *Lets say I want to run a query that will return all the films that a specific actor has participated in.*

**solution :**

```
val nested_json = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("\\directors.json")//path to json file 
import spark.implicits._
val films_directors_df = nested_json.select("director","films.name")
val films_directors_flatten = films_directors_df.withColumn("name",explode($"name")).as("films")
films_directors_flatten.show(false)
val mys = nested_json.select("films")
val films__flatten = mys.withColumn("films",explode($"films"))
val actors_name_df = films__flatten.select("films.actors","films.name")
//actors_name_df.show(false) //contains both actors across film
val actors_name_flatten = actors_name_df.withColumn("actors",explode($"actors")).as("actors")
actors_name_flatten.show(false)
val final_df = films_directors_flatten
  .join(actors_name_flatten,$"films.name"===$"actors.name")
  .select($"films.director" as "directors",$"films.name" as "films",$"actors.actors" as "actors")
final_df.show(false)


final_df is the dataframe where you can query for all films that a specific actor has participated in. This solves your above question.
sample query : final_df.filter($"actors"==="Henry Thomas").show(false)

Cheers!!
```